# Why is my list count 8 after adding only 4 items?

Tags: vb.net, list, csv, io

I have a csv file `Questions.csv` containing the following:

```
Question ID, A, B, C, 
1, TestA, TestB, TestC
2, TestA, TestB, TestC
3, TestA, TestB, TestC
```

In my code i have the following method to read from the file and create a Question object using the values and then add the Question object to a list.

```
Public Sub getQuestionsAndAnswers()

Dim allQuestions As New List(Of Question)

Using ioReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("Resources/Questions.csv")

    ioReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    ioReader.SetDelimiters(",")
    'ioReader.ReadFields()
    While Not ioReader.EndOfData

        Dim arrCurrentRow As String() = ioReader.ReadFields()
        Dim aQuestion As Question = New Question(arrCurrentRow(0), arrCurrentRow(1), arrCurrentRow(2))
        allQuestions.Add(aQuestion)

    End While

End Using
```

When i check the size of the list using `allQuestions.count()` it is equal to 8. Why is it saying 8 items are within the list when there should be only 4?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugging functionality and checking the items in the list? This may help with finding a solution to your problem

Comment: allQuestions.count() will equal the number of elements in your list. As Jaxi said to find what questions are making up the further 4 in your list you need to debug.

Comment: Your code works as expected. There must be something else going on, in code not shown...

Comment: I concur with @Neal.  I ran the code and got 4 items.

Answer (score 0):

While not ideal, this works for me:

```
Public Sub getQuestionsAndAnswers()
    Dim allQuestions As New List(Of Question)

    Using ioReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("Resources/Questions.csv")

        ioReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        ioReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        'ioReader.ReadFields()
        While Not ioReader.EndOfData

            Dim arrCurrentRow As String() = ioReader.ReadFields(0).Split(",")
            Dim aQuestion As Question = New Question(arrCurrentRow(0), arrCurrentRow(1), arrCurrentRow(2))
            allQuestions.Add(aQuestion)

        End While

    End Using
End Sub
```

Checked in my code and with this it returns 4 results, although I had to do my extra Split because without it the code threw an exception due to the delimiter not actually working...